# Android FirebaseUI get extra info about user from from provider

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm using FirebaseUI Android for users login with following code:

```
 startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setLogo(R.drawable.firebase_auth_120dp)
                        .setProviders(getSelectedProviders())
                        .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                        .setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
                        .build(),
                RC_SIGN_IN);

private String[] getSelectedProviders() {
        ArrayList<String> selectedProviders = new ArrayList<>();
        selectedProviders.add(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER);
        selectedProviders.add(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER);
        selectedProviders.add(AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER);
        return selectedProviders.toArray(new String[selectedProviders.size()]);
    }
```

And getting data from `onActivityResult` with following code:

```
if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            handleSignInResponse(resultCode, data);
            return;
        }
```

Everything is OK. I'm getting user's Display name, email, photo url, and uid with following:

```
FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
currentUser.*();
```

Now I'm getting just limited data about user. I also want user's date of birth, bio and interest etc. How I can get that?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been answered here: [Firebase Auth get additional user info (age, gender)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39249043/firebase-auth-get-additional-user-info-age-gender)

> Unfortunately, Firebase doesn't have any built-in functionality to get the user's gender/birthdate upon successful login. You would have to retrieve these data from each of the providers yourself.