# More user data from firebase_auth plugin in Flutter

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-signin

I have implemented firebase auth (through Google) on Flutter, but I cannot seem to be able to retrieve more user data other than email, picture and name.

I'm interested in age and sex of users.
Also, I don't know why but also on the firebase dashboard those data don't seem to be retrieved after login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Firebase doesn't provide these information, for retrieving that, you can use the ID that you retrieved after the login with external services.

E.g. for gender you can use https://developers.google.com/people/ API.

Flutter seems like a package that is developed by Google Engineers, for Google APIs including people, you can use it. (I haven't done this operation on Flutter, I know it from Android.)

If you are familiar with Android you can [check this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39249043/firebase-auth-get-additional-user-info-age-gender).

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I'll check the people api.